# Clearing dpkg downloaded data?

Tags: dpkg, ios

I'm using dpkg (Cydia), and a package keeps saying that it's downloading 26.2 MB, and resuming at 166.0 kB. It is consistently failing to install properly. Is there a way to clear this "saved data" and start the download fresh again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian-based systems, apt-get downloads *.deb files under `/var/cache/apt/archives/` (dpkg does not download anything by itself, it only manages the packages locally).

Searching suggests, it's just a bit different on iOS, and the path is [`/private/var/cache/apt/archives`](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki//private/var/cache/apt/archives), partucularly, you probably want to remove `/private/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb`

Comment: Works great, `/var` symlinks to `/private/var` on iOS.